# How to get the Selected Data Items from KendoDropDowntree when checkboxes is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using kendo dropdowntree with checkboxes enabled.
I need to get the entire data item of the selected nodes when the change is triggered.
Currently, I'm getting only the Value field of the selected Items.
How to get the entire Item?

```
<script>
$("#dropdowntree").kendoDropDownTree({
 dataSource: [{ text: "item1", value: 1 }, { text: "item2", value: 2 },{ text: "item3", value: 3 }],
 checkboxes: true,
 change: function(e) {
   var value = this.value();
   // Here I need the checked dataItems as full objects, instead of just values
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it does not appear as though Kendo exposes the selected dataItems, so you will need to do it manually.

The parameter `e` exposes the widget that triggered the event via `e.sender`. From there you can filter the widget's dataSource by the value returned by `this.value`.

Take a look at this example:

```js
change: function(e) {
  var value = this.value();
  var dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
  var dataItems = e.sender.dataSource.data().filter(dataItem => value.indexOf(dataItem.value) > -1);
  console.log(dataItems);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/eKaFojav